# How accomplish specific soap formatting using c# .net 3.5

Tags: .net, soap

the client wants the xml/soap response of my web service exactly like this below; the body must be empty.
how can I accomplish this in c# .net 3.5? I'm using VS 2008.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http:"//www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> 
<soap:Header>
 <wsa:MessageID>blah</wsa:MessageID>
 <wsa:RelatesTo>blah</wsa:RelatesTo>
 <wsa:To>blah</wsa:To>
 <wsa:Action>blah</wsa:Action>
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client should supply you with access to the WSDL, preferably through a URL. You should then use "Add Service Reference" to consume that service.

See [How to consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/) to learn how web services are generally consumed. Hint: you almost never need to manipulate XML.

Comment: John, I should have said "the client of my web service", he/she is the one consuming my web service and wants the response like that. She's already calling my web method successfully but I cannot figure out how to format my response like that.

Comment: How have you created the service. Again, it should not be necessary to manipulate XML! If you are thinking of building such an XML response, then you are almost certainly doing it wrong, without  understanding web services.

Comment: The question is, is this xml valid? and if so, is there a c# .net 3.5 program that returns such xml "elegantly"? Ok, xmlns:soap="http:"//www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope should be xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" , Now is the question, is this xml valid?

Comment: I strongly urge you to stop right now and learn a little bit about web services before proceeding. Due to your ignorance of the subject (and possibly the ignorance of your client), you are proceeding as though this were an exercise in generating XML. If you do it properly, the correct XML will be generated for you and you'll never need to think about XML again.